# Create a transfer order with an Empty Vendor number

Tags: abap, sap-erp, warehouse

I have a requirement where I have to create a transfer order with empty vendor.

The scenario is:

- The client wants to maintain its in-house stock, and in-house stock does not have any Special Stock no. (Vendor) in table `LQUA`.
- If this stock is available then the transfer order should be created with `LTAP-SONUM` = Empty.

I am trying the login in EXIT: `EXIT_SAPLMDBF_002`

I am currently applying `C_XT434P-BPRIO = Empty` and `C_XT434P-LIFNR =  Empty` in my EXIT after the stock validation.

But still SAP standard re-calculate the Vendor and assigns it an Consignment Vendor.

But if I assign an consignment vendor in the EXIT i.e. `C_XT434P-BPRIO = 'K'` and `C_XT434P-LIFNR = Consignment Vendor no.`, then Transfer order is created with the vendor I have assigned.

Please help me in creating Transfer order with Empty Vendor.